# How to display block by 100% of container-fluid?

Tags: html, css

There is block:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="body_wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

How to show block `.body_wrapper` by 100% of content with margin from body borders?

Comment: an unstyled `<div>` does already have 100% width because of `display: block` is the browser default style. Or are you using some kind of framework? Your not telling in your question?

Comment: Not only have you not mentioned if you are asking about height or width, you have not provided any css of what you tried. Furthermore, are you needing 100% of parent or browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some content and use `width: 100%` in body_wrapper css

```css
.body_wrapper {
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="body_wrapper">
  Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to specify a width. A `display: block;` is already filling to the edges.

Comment: by height 100%, not width

Comment: @OPV please modify your question and be more clear what you except. Add more details.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink Yes a ```display: block``` also does the job. But what if it was other ```display``` option? I just showed another way to do the trick.